# Update DataTable in R Shiny based on user clicks on buttons in DataTable rows

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt, shinyjs

I am attempting to create a data table in R Shiny that updates (removes rows) after a user clicks on a button in the row that says "Add." For context, this is a fantasy football app I am making for myself to help me draft.

I have been able to create actionButtons for every row, and I can get the id of the player clicked on to show up in a box on the right that says: "Selected: /playerID/." I have tried to update the initial dataframe (active_league()) by filtering upon the ID of the selected player - I have tried an eventReactive and observeEvent, based on a click of an actionButton: "Draft Player", but it doesn't update the table. I also tried to create another data frame with just the "added player"'s stats, and then anti_joining with active_league() by = 'id, but that also does not update the datatable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(shinyjs)

grandview_superbowl_projections <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/day536/ffanalytics/master/web_scrape_data/grandview_superbowl_projections.csv") %>%
  filter(avg_type == "weighted")
hester_projections <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/day536/ffanalytics/master/web_scrape_data/hester_projections.csv") %>%
  filter(avg_type == "weighted")


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    size = "", color = "teal",
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(tabName = "board", "Board"),

      menuSubItem(
        selectInput("league", label = "", choices = c("Grandview SB", "Hester")),
        actionButton("update", "Update League", class = "fluid ui primary button")
      )
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(useShinyjs(),

                tabItem(tabName = "board",
                        br(),
                        h1("Draft Board"),

                        fluidRow(width = 16,
                                 column(width = 12,
                                        box(DT::dataTableOutput('board'), width = 12)),
                                 column(width = 4,
                                        fluidRow(width = 4, box(selectInput('boardpos', 'Position', choices = grandview_superbowl_projections$pos), width = 4)),
                                        fluidRow(width = 4, box(selectInput('boardteam', 'Team', choices = grandview_superbowl_projections$team), width = 4)),
                                        fluidRow(width = 4, box(textOutput('myText'), br(), actionButton('submit_drafted_player', "Draft Player", class = "fluid ui primary button"), width = 4))
                                 )
                        ))

  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # SWITCH TO ACTIVE LEAGUE DATA --------------------------------------
  active_league <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    switch(input$league,
           "Grandview SB" = grandview_superbowl_projections,
           "Hester" = hester_projections)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


  # FUNCTION TO CREATE ACTION BUTTONS ----------------------------------
  shinyInput <- function(FUN, n, id, ...) {

    # for each of n, create a new input using the FUN function and convert
    # to a character
    vapply(seq_len(n), function(i){
      as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }, character(1))

  }

  # CREATE REACTIVE DF OF DRAFT BOARD  -----------------------------------
  boardtable <- reactive({

    active_league() %>%
      filter(avg_type == "weighted") %>%
      arrange(rank) %>%
      filter(rank < 7) %>%
      select(id, "Name" = full_name, "Team" = team, "Pos" = pos, "Proj. Points" = points, "Floor VOR" = floor_vor, "VOR" = points_vor, "Ceiling VOR" = ceiling_vor, "Risk" = risk) %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1) %>%
      mutate(Draft = shinyInput(
        FUN = actionButton,
        n = n(),
        id = 'button_',
        label = "Add",
        onclick = 'Shiny.setInputValue(\"select_button\", this.id, {priority: \"event\"})',
        class = "ui primary button"))
  })

  # DT OUTPUT -----------------------------------------------------------
  output$board <- DT::renderDT({

    boardtable() 

  }, escape = F, selection = 'none',  options = list(pageLength = 25)
  )

  # SELECT BUTTON TO DECLARE DRAFTED PLAYER ------------------------------
  draftee <- eventReactive(input$select_button, {
    # take the value of input$select_button, e.g. "button_1"
    # get the button number (1) and assign to selectedRow
    selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])

    # get the value of the "Name" column in the data.frame for that row
    paste(boardtable()[selectedRow,"id"])
  })


  # PRINT NAME OF PLAYER PICKED    
  # Show the name of the draftee that has been clicked on

  output$myText <- renderText({

    paste0("Selected: ", as.numeric(draftee()[1]))

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect the input$submit_drafted_player to update the table upon being clicked. When clicked, the table will remove the player who was drafted. I have tried multiple eventReactives and observeEvents with this button and cannot get the table to update.

Comment: Your button is labelled "Add" and its role is to remove a row ? Isnt'it strange, or I misunderstand something?

Comment: Hi Stéphane, the “Add” button was meant to send the players name to the box on the right side, where the players name will show up. The “Draft Player” button in that box on the right would then confirm to draft that player and remove them from the list. If I could change the buttons in the table to say “Draft” and have it remove the player from the row upon a click, that would be an acceptable alternative as well. Thought it might be easier though to have a two part action where a user “adds” a player to be drafted and then “confirms” the selection.